# snyk wizard error while creating MEAN app

Tags: mean.io

i am new to MEAN stack development. while i am running `snyk wizard` i am getting the following error. What does it actually mean and how to solve it?

```
Snyk couldn't patch the specified vulnerabilities because GNU's patch is not available. Please install 'patch' and try again.
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using gnu/Linux and don’t have patch installed. I am also assuming that snyk uses patch to fix files for vulnerabilities. Try installing patch and running the command again